# How can I lease my EOS once the mainnet launches?

Tags: tokens, mainnet, leasing

EOS has been described as the blockchain real-estate due to its ability to allow it's holders to lease their tokens to dApp developers once the mainnet launches in June 2018 but I've heard very little about how this will work. I have a few questions:

1. How can I lease my tokens?
2. Is there an easy way for me to find dApp developers looking to lease EOS?
3. In what form would I be compensated for this leasing?
4. Would I be expected to work out a contract with
   the developer manually (offline) or are there automated methods in place where I could be compensated in crypto?
5. Are leasing periods variable length (we decide) or a specific length and can they be cancelled prematurely by the lessor or leasee?

Comment: @kenorb, @Glorfindel, @PeterJ, @MEE, @Nikita, It was foolish of you to close a question that's been answered and up-voted by the community already. The rules regarding broad questions are clear: 
`too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format`

The accepted answer is not as long as a book and the valid answers are easily determined as such. There was no reason to close this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Chintai is building a dApp (decentralized app) on the EOS blockchain
   that will allow you to lease your tokens. You can view it here: https://chintai-eos.io/
2. They will likely be on the Chintai marketplace, or other similar marketplaces.
3. You will be compensated in EOS tokens.
4. It will likely be an automated process on leasing marketplaces.
5. You will likely be able to control this on the leasing marketplaces.