# Are there benefits to holding EOS as a user?

Tags: tokens, dapp, ram-allocation, airdrops

From what I understand holding EOS gives developers access to RAM and possibly storage.

So developers and investors hoping to launch sites will want to hold EOS. I'm very interested in EOS and want to participate but mainly as a user of DApps.

Will EOS be required for user's who simply want to be users on DApps?

If it isn't required will there be an added benefit to holding more? I'm familiar with STEEM where new users essentially get a loan of 15 STEEM allowing them to use the site, but a user can power up with additional STEEM for added benefits.

I know with Everipedia the plan is that EOS holders get an Air-Drop. So does that mean after an Air-Drop happens there is no benefit to holding EOS for an Everipedia power-user? They would instead want to hold Everipedia tokens and then Everipedia as a whole would be holding EOS tokens that would allocate them the RAM and bandwidth needed to run their DApp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users of the EOS network will not require any holdings to interface with dApps.

As you mentioned Airdrops are certainly a benefit of owning EOS, many companies are using this as a way to circumvent the ICO restrictions by the SEC and also by the large tech companies banning ICO advertisements.

Once the Everipedia airdrops ends, there will be more, currently there's around 12 official airdrops, many happening around June and we should assume this is just the beginning.

Further, owning tokens allows the network resources your EOS allots you to be leased to developers in need of more bandwidth. This could mean a steady source of income for you without ever needing to expend tokens.

Comment: As far as I understand, as a user you do need to have tokens to stake for the bandwidth of the transactions you produce above certain free tier, as it is the user and not the application who pays for the bandwidth

Comment: @ArielScarpinelli no, the developer stakes what's necessary for their application to run. There's also no 'free tier', you stake what you need. If you use more than you're entitled to and the network can handle it there's no throttling. If the network can't handle it, the network goes into stake-only mode and you can only use what you're entitled to.

Comment: Continued -> If a dApp is made properly, there's no reason the user needs to know they're interacting with a blockchain at all.

Comment: According to this chat https://pasteboard.co/HkZapDA.png users are the ones paying for BW and the staking goes the other way around, from app to user.

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/9be89106da1d6a1543eb19dd0f3b96a53e286088/libraries/chain/transaction_context.cpp#L84

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/9be89106da1d6a1543eb19dd0f3b96a53e286088/libraries/chain/resource_limits.cpp#L112

Answer (score 2):

There could be benefits yes, depending on which dApps a user might interact with.

It might be possible that a dApp will require a user to stake tokens to the dApp to power it, and/or for storage, either for access, or to gain access to additional features/capacity.

This will depend on the business model a particular dApp chooses to adopt of course, and which dApps a given user chooses to consume.

Answer (score 0):

As a dapp user you're not required to hold tokens, you can use and interact with the dapp without holding restrictions. 
For an investor, EOS token will allow you to receive airdrops and you can also rent your tokens in order to gain a passive income with https://www.chintai-eos.io/

Comment: I am curious how the rent will be paid. More EOS tokens?

Comment: @Stilgar that seems to be likely, see: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-can-i-lease-my-eos-once-the-mainnet-launches/57#57